# Best strategy to maximize winning between 2 competitors asked to choose number

Tags: game-theory

Two guys are asked to think of a number between 0 and 100. If guy A chooses number greater than B than A wins 10 paid by the house and B gets nothing. If B chooses number greater than A then B gets 10 paid by the house and A gets nothing. If both choose same number then both end up paying 10 each to the house. What is the best strategy to choose a number. (guys can not communicate with each-other).

Comment: If $A$ gets a higher number than $B$, does $B$ pay $A$ or does the house pay $A$?

Comment: The house pays to A

Comment: To get started:  If we think about the case in which we can only choose $0,1$, then  the Nash equilibrium is to choose $0$ with probability $\frac 13$.  If, say, $A$ commits to this then choosing $0$  for $B$ has expectation $-10\times \frac 13$ whereas choosing $1$ has expectation $-10\times \frac 23+10\times \frac 13$ which is the same.

Comment: Hint:  that method works generally, with some effort.  if $p_i$ is the equilibrium probability of choosing $i$, then (assuming $A$ commits to this) if $B$ chooses $0$ his expectation is $E_0=-10p_0$.  Similarly $E_1=10p_0-10p_1$ and $E_0=E_1\implies p_0=\frac 12p_1$.  Keep going.

Comment: Not sure if this is the right way

Comment: What's your objection?  It gives a pretty simple closed formula for $p_i$.  Are you looking for something other than the Nash equilibrium?

Comment: Assume there should be no cheating in the meaning of optimizing both players sum and share the benefit. Suggest to simplify the game to numbers between 0 and 1, 0 and 2 and then generalize.

Comment: Lets say I am A, what number should i choose?

Comment: Lets say you are B, what number should you choose?

Comment: This game is a brilliant idea to start a competition between programmed robots (if it is original).

Comment: The strategy has to be probabilistic.  You choose $i$ with probability $p_i$ (with values $p_i$ as determined in my hint).

Comment: Choosing any number other than $100$ all the time is clearly a bad idea (as your opponent will simply choose $100$).  Choosing $100$ all the time is something of a degenerate strategy...if both parties do that that locks in the worst possible outcome.  One side or the other could simply capitulate of course and allow their opponent to win all the time.

Comment: @lulu, is there any sense, if the opponent knows that you are using your recommended strategy? Simply, always choose 100 or 99 - then you should temporary modify yours.

Comment: @z100  My solution gives the Nash equilibrium...so if I stick to my guns, there's no point in your varying your strategy.  By definition, your expected return is the same whatever you choose.  Of course, in a repetitive situation, both of us might seek to deviate from the equilibrium.  The repetitive strategy of "always choose $100$" is frustrating, though...if you believe I mean it, you can optimize your return by giving up and letting me win forever.  Hard to believe it would play out that way, however.

Comment: This is very complicated, how would two robots play this?

Comment: @Chaos, it is a very simple game, an example of robot canalways choose 42, another one always 100, 3rd one 99, one can choose random etc

Comment: @lulu, what do youthink about the method similar to find or communicate with extraterrestrial inteligence. So to somehow player A find out the strategy of player B which includes a message and vice versa. Exchanging the message would finally lead to playboth players against the house.

Comment: @z100 if robot chooses random then I will always choose 100 against it and win, so choosing random is not the optimum solution for the robot

Comment: It is about figuring out the strategy of the other player and optimizing yours

Comment: @z100, don't see it...sorry.  It's not a "good" game, in two ways:  first, the Nash equilibrium has negative expectation (as choosing $0$ has negative expectation).  Who'd sign up for that?  Second, the asymmetric equilibria (one of us chooses $100$ all the time, the other gives up) actually improves the expectation for both players.  Cooperative strategies (where we pool the winnings, or alternate victories) would clearly lead to one of those (or something equivalent).  That is, the Nash equilibrium does not optimize expectation.

Comment: @Chaos  Any deterministic strategy is a dead loser.  Remember, $A$ and $B$ are perfectly symmetric.  If I decide that, say, $67$ is the optimal number then so do you so we both will say $67$.  The probabilistic strategy gives us both a strong chance of winning (though there is still a good chance that we'll tie, especially at $100$).

Comment: @z100  an interesting question might be "how could non-communicating robots best arrive at the alternating strategy"?  or something like that. In an iterative game...if I just alternate $100,0$ regardless of what you do, you'd work that out and start doing the opposite, no?  Gets worse, of course, if you actually lose something when I win.

Comment: @lulu, would you not play with this game?? Would you not beat the house? There is a solution where the two robots will converge! Its not a one number solution I am sure!

Comment: + lulu, if i figure out you are using probabilitic strategy then i will choose 100 and beat you! So probabilistic may not be the best strategy, and the solution may not be symmetrical

Comment: I wouldn't play one round!  If I could play it iteratively, I would...as I am confident that we could sort out the alternating strategy.  But any route to that would require some randomization of strategies.

Comment: You keep saying that, but you are wrong.  "probabilistic" does not mean uniform.  Consider the $0,1$ case....in that case, the Nash equilibrium has you choose $1$ two thirds of the time.  So if you always choose the largest number you lose most of the time...it is set so that no strategy on your part changes your expectation.  That's the definition of the Nash equilibrium.

Comment: You wouldnt play one round!!!! Why dont you just choose 83, what are the chances of other choosing 83 as well for you to pay out

Answer (score 0):

What happens if B chooses greater than A? If nothing happens, then the best strategy is for A to choose 100, and B to choose 0.

A is motivated to do so because of the three possible outcomes, he either:

1. gets $10 - if he chooses higher
2. gets $0 - if he chooses lower
3. loses $10 - if he chooses the same

B is motivated to do so because of the three possible outcomes, he either:

1. gets $0 - if he chooses higher
2. gets $0 - if he chooses lower
3. loses $10 - if he chooses the same

B will be indifferent between options 1 and 2. So, to avoid the chance of losing $10 (option B-3), he will choose as low a number as possible.

A will obviously prefer option 1. So, to avoid the chance of losing $10 (Option A-3), he will choose as high as possible.

Hence A=100, B=0

Comment: Sorry edited the comment, B

Comment: Sorry edited the question, If B chooses number greater than A then B gets 10 and A gets nothing

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

Let's assume players after the game receive only the information about the result - pay (equal), get (higher), or nothing (lower) and the goal is to get paid more (not to win the opponent by higher score).
Maximum summary for players is 10 per game. Since  the game is symmetric, the maximum benefit for a player is 5 per game. It is achievable with alternate strategy where players wins every 2nd game. e.g. using strategy 100-99-100-99... for player A and 99-100-99-100-99... for player B for all games after N-th game for some finite number N.

Strategy also works with 0 (means "I really want you to win in this game") instead of 99 ("I want you to win only, if choose 100"),
but if another player really always wants to loose it is a winning strategy to exploit such behaviour.

Now, what is missing here? If the other player does not or does not want to understand the optimal strategy or is a "100 always robot"  the best strategy for player A is 99 always to get/lose zero. So it becomes the 10€ per game winning strategy for the other player.

Comment: not quite the solution, the players cant communicate, obviously the best is not to choose same number and both cooperate to win alternatively, but thats not what is going to happen, the robots will not cooperate, each will be trying to make the maximum

Comment: @Chaos Also robots may use AI. It is not easy to communicate however not impossible - in simplified case player after the game knows the opponents number (in our case this information is not necessary - but there is still a part of useful information, just the method using statistics and probability is more complicated), and sequence may transport a message, like "8 5 12 12 15" ("hello"). So if the game consists of 1 million parts, it is easy to exchange the strategy in first few hundred  and then  empty the house.